# Trusting a big name brand employer that seems unstable

Tags: recruitment, job-offer

After about 6 interviews with a big MNC that included an IQ test and a personality/behavioral assessment with some sort of shrink, the MNC extended a "verbal" offer, complete with pay, PTO and benefits structuring. Based on this, I turned down two other offers from smaller companies. Two days later, MNC informs my recruiter that they've run into funding issues regarding my specific position so they're unable to extend a formal offer letter. I was first irritated that such a huge shop will go headhunting without first securing the funds and after making me jump thru so many hoops, and reassuring me I was safe to consider them provisional employers (turning down other offers). I've since moved on.

Fast forward a month later, they're back, and whispering sweet nothings. I already have a gig I'm quite happy with. I should mention however that this MNC has a very unique niche of the finance market and offers experience and training I will almost certainly not get anywhere else and working for them (prior to their SNAFU) and getting that training/experience was a dream.

Would I be daft to consider them at this point, having been burnt by them once on what seemed to be a no-brainer?

Comment: there is no such thing as "stable" anymore ... especially in the finance market, they define un-stable.

Comment: There is at least one company I have no interest in working for because they rescinded a job offer they had made in writing and I had accepted. I think it's up to you - would you feel confident in your future job with them? If not, even if it is felt irrationally, I wouldn't, because you have a lot more to worry about in life than worrying about your job is secure because of a past experience.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Budgets are a funny thing, in particular in large companies. One day there will have the budget, the next they won't, the day after that, they will...

That's simple reality in large companies and many times not the fault of the hiring manager.

What you should do is not reject other offers or give your notice **until** you have the formal offer letter in hand and signed by the company representatives.

You need to consider whether the training is more important to you than the aggravation caused (which you can't know the reason for).

Comment: Completely agree here.  The op decided to turn down offers with out a firm offer in hand.  It does not sound like it was done with malice by the MNC.

Comment: Aye, I was quick to make that decision. To be honest, I only ever had eyes for the MNC, turning down the other offers came pretty easily to me. But I daresay the costs of all the screenings and hoops I jumped thru were not insignificant. I was told at a particular stage(by a third party in the process) that the evaluation I was going thru did not come cheap at all. No such thing as too big to fail I see.

Answer (score 10):

Large corporations are usually not coherent entities. They're more like feudal organizations with many fiefdoms of different sizes with a "king" (CEO) at the top. So you'll have numerous groups and managers with their own budgets that act more or less independently of the larger nation that is the company. Sourcing and recruitment can often become somewhat of a quagmire when it comes to figuring out where the money will come from.

I've seen many similar situations where managers get stuck in a kind of catch-22. They need to get a project to their team to get a budget but they need more resources on the team to be able to handle the project but they need a budget to hire someone...

What the crafty manager often does is to simply get started on recruiting to fill up the team with the assumption that as long as they've got the resources lined up, they'll get the project and the budget needed to actually go through with the hirings.

Sometimes this doesn't pan out and people end up like you, burned. But for the manager, doing it like this is not a choice, it's the only way to try and break the internal log-jam. I'm not defending it, I'm just saying it's the way it is. That's why we keep saying "nothing's final until the contract is signed", and maybe not even then if you read all the fine-print.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the big name, It really counts for nothing these days.

If you think that in your current job even few months or years down the line you will not be able to get the kind of exposure or trainings that you will get in the MNC from first day then you should think about joining the MNC otherwise it's always better to work in a small company (esp if you are happy there).

Comment: -1. This is a lot of unqualified statements. A big name counts for nothing these days?  it's "always better to work in a small company"? I certainly didn't realize these were universally accepted as true!

Comment: This is a comment more than an answer.  You need to provide support for your assertions.

Comment: Huh? Big names don't count? I strongly beg to differ.

Answer (score 2):

As Vivek said, *there is no need to switch from a small company, if you are happy there* unless you have heard about the working environment of the next company.

As per my experience, i would prefer to work with a MNC. ***Brand Name Does matter.***

I would like to mention my case here, which is quite a bit similar to your case. I was placed in a top IT company, a year ago. In between i started job with a small company at home town. Now i am going to join that MNC in 2 or 3 months. MY reasons for this is that, the growth that i will get in the MNC will be far, ***far*** better than, what i got in the small company. Second, it will be better for future aspect(My career experience), Third, getting exposure of working with a large company.

I am not against vivek's point, but just presenting my point of view.

So, i would prefer you to join the MNC. but first you need to clarify some points about **Your Job Scope** and other growth aspects that you think does matter.

Comment: Yes but these MNC's are not really global brands are they? more like local country based companies that are putting on a front.