# I have verbally accepted an offer at company A. How to handle other offers?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process

I have been at interviews at company A and B. Today i received a verbal offer from company A, but they said that I would probably not receive the contract before 3 weeks time. I have no preference between A and B. How should i react if company B also offers me a job? I think it would be very dishonest to say yes, as I have already said yes to company A. But I feel a bit uncertain as I don't have anything in paper. I think that it is very unlikely that company A will not follow through as it is a very well respected company, but I of course can't know for certain. I also have an interview at company C next week. Should I cancel this interview now? I would rather work for A than C.

I don't know if it relevant, but none of these jobs are full-time positions. I'm  a 20 years old university student.

Comment: Related: [How to renege implicit verbal acceptance of a job offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4478)

Comment: VTC - this question already has an answer as noted in the comments by @DanPichelman

Answer (score 6):

As long as you don’t have a signed contract, you have nothing. Your verbal acceptance doesn’t count. And with three weeks between offer and contract, it’s their own fault if they lose you.

If you get an offer from B, you go with the better offer. You can also tell A that you have another offer where they will decide earlier. That might speed A up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb: Never stop marketing yourself until the ink is dry on your written contract!

You can tell the other company´s B and C that you already have an offer on the table. Also you can afford to scrutinize your would-be jobs at company B and C a little bit more. Its unlikely they are all exactly the same.

If you have a competing offer from B or C, it´s also okay to tell A that you´ll need at least a physical offer letter to be sure and turn down the other opprotunities.

Answer (score 1):

Until you have a signed contract, IMHO, you cannot see yourself as hired these days.

Look after #1 - You

Especially when you say, that A,B or C has not significant difference for you

Answer (score 0):

> Today i received a verbal offer from company A, but they said that I would probably not receive the contract before 3 weeks time.

That's a good sign, but it doesn't mean you should stop looking.  In the off chance that they do fall through and you do not get the job offer, it would be to your benefit to keep looking at jobs.

> How should i react if company B also offers me a job?

I would tell them that you want to take some time to think about it.  There is nothing wrong in this approach and if the company does want you to work for them then they would be willing to wait.  Turning down a job offer is not unprofessional.

> I also have an interview at company C next week. Should I cancel this interview now?

I wouldn't.  There's no problem in simply turning down a job offer from company C if company A gets back to you.  Your verbal offer has no legal weight until it is in writing, so while the offer is a good sign, I wouldn't pop the brakes just yet.